# Char to int implicit cast Behind the Scenes

Tags: c#, operators, implicit-conversion

The following is valid in c# as `Char` can be implicitly cast to `int`

```
int i = 'a';
```

i am just curious about what .Net Framework do behind the scenes, i looked in to `char` and `int` types source code but unable to find where it's written.

Can any body explain what happens behind the scene?

Comment: Can't say how it is done behind the scene but its ASCII value will be stored in `i`. It also works the same way in C/C++.

Comment: i am trying to look at the source code of it to see what is actually going on

Comment: Is C# compiler open source ? I guess new `roslyn` is open sourced. Please point out the code when you find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C# we have something that is called a *Single-Rooted unified type system*. That means every existing type is a subtype of one root type. `Object` in C#. So `char` or `int` is only short (alias) for `System.Char` and `System.Int32`. The conversion from an untyped `Object` to `long` or `char` (value types) is called `(un)boxing`.

This is a real difference compared to *Java* where there are the primitive types `int`,`char`.. and there is `Object`. Java classes like `Int` are wrapping the primitive types. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_C_Sharp_and_Java

Because in C# everything is an `Object` (*I am Object, for we are many!*), all the value types implement `IConvertible`, as the others said.

And there is a mostly internally used enum `TypeCode` that is the runtime reflection info that is assigned to value type object´s like `int`. The `Convert.To` method´s are using this type information to do their job.

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs

The mscorlib (System namespace) can be found on github under https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/tree/master/src/mscorlib/src/System

Further because value types are full objects (struct) lots of type/meta information is available during runtime.

C# is a safe(er) language compared to c++ for example. It does not allow unsafe impilict casts.

The cast from `char` to `int` is a `widening`. `Int` is bigger/has more space than `char`. It´s safe to cast.

But that´s why it is not the same as `(int) 'a'` like Joanvo wrote.
This is an explicit cast and you are forcing .Net to do it, no matter it´s safe or not.

For `int i = 'a';` it´s fine to do an implicit cast because of the widening. 
But if you try `char c = 42;` Visual Studio and the compiler will not allow it. Unless you force it with an explicit cast while being aware that maybe not all information from the `int` will fit into the `char`

This is also the reason why you can not use something different than a boolean (expression) inside an *if*.

In C/C++ you can write `if(1) { }` or `if(0) {}`. That is not allowed in C#, where you have to write `if(..==1) {}`. In C/C++ this is often used to check pointer for *null*.

You can overload the `implicit` and `explicit` operator for own types, which is useful sometimes. At least useful to know it is possible. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx

Answer (score 3):

As @shahwat and @joanvo said its the ASCII value that will be stored in i.

See this,

```
  char value = 'a';
        Console.WriteLine(value);
        Console.WriteLine((int)value);
        Console.WriteLine(value == 'y');
        Console.WriteLine(value.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(char));
        Console.WriteLine((int)char.MinValue);
        Console.WriteLine((int)char.MaxValue);



   Out Put:
    a
    97                  (Integer value of char)
    False
    System.Char
    System.Char
    0                   (MinValue as an integer)
    65535               (MaxValue as an integer)
```

**Edit:**
[microsoft](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/boolean.cs)
On this microsoft reference you can find the implementation of every method.
Just need to click on specific method and you will be navigated to the defination of that method.

You can also add specific VS extension related to your requirement
For ex:
[Download VS extensions](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f89b27c5-7d7b-4059-adde-7ccc709fa86e)
by this way you would have a functionality in your VS and you can see the implementation by just right cicking on the methods and selecting "Go to Defination"

For your scenario

```
int i ='a';
```

This is not really a method (in some sense).
To view its implementation you have to use
[roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn)

I am not sure would this be possible in case of Resharper , but i have just provided a way by which you can get this done.Hope this would be some help to you.

Here is a step by step guide for your scenario:
1.Setup Environment (Install VS,Roslyn)  here
[roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn)
2.Enable .NET Framework Source debug (if its not enabled by default)
[Enable Source Debug](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410(v=vs.140).aspx)
3.Put a break point on your statement `int i='a'`
4.Press f11 to step through all the implementation which is written behind this statement.

Thats all you have to do.

**Imp note:**
I would like to add one more thing that if above method does not worked for you ,then it would be something related to MSIL.So in that case you need to analyse what Roslyn generates from this code.
And if this is the case then you can also check it with any Reflector tool that will show you the generated MSIL.

Comment: you mean to say is we cannot see source code of a dll??

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I mean visual studio has no builtin functionality to show the source code of these dll's, but there are tons of softwares available to see what is written in dll. See this  http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

http://ilspy.net/ this also    http://filegenreflector.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Sadaquat i am using Resharper to see the source code of `Char` and `int` types

Comment: @EhsanSajjad so what problem are you facing using Resharper?

Comment: i am unable to find the implementation where it is done

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I will be right back with an edited answer ,mean while you can just check this link   http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/boolean.cs,f1b135ff6c380b37

Comment: @EhsanSajjad   let me know ,do you got what you were asking for?

Comment: i am interested to see the implementation, unfortunately i am unable to find it and you also have not pointed out where it is written

Comment: @EhsanSajjad As i have mentioned that you can see the implementation using roslyn all you have to do is to add a break point to your statement int i='x'; and press f11 you will be step through all the methods involving this implementation (to enable .NET Source debug visit  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410(v=vs.140).aspx).

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I don't know  the namespace or class where it is written but  i have provided you a step by step process through which you can see the  source code of .NET Framework. If you have any issue in setting up Environment or any other help let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The source code for the .NET primitive types is at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/, as indicated by @Sadaquat.

The specific implementation you're talking about is probably the [implementation of `IConvertable.ToInt32()` from the `Char` struct](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/char.cs,02f2b1a33b09362d).

That simply returns [`Convert.ToInt32(char value)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,21f17073b87b47b0), which itself simply returns the value, since `char`s are integer values behind the scenes.