# How does this LINQ query get initial values for this string?

Tags: c#, linq

I do not quite understand how this C# code (using LINQ) is working. From my my understanding, the characters are iterated over and multiplied by 30 and then summed. How is initial value for say "A" acquired?

```
string characters = "ABC";
characters = characters.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
Console.WriteLine(characters.ToUpper().Select(c => (c * 30)).Sum());
```

Comment: The numeric value of a `char` is its Unicode code point. In the case of `A`, that would be 65.

Comment: A simple experiment: `char a = 'A'; Console.WriteLine((int)a);`

Comment: Sorry, just out of interest, where did you see this code? Because outside of a textbook, this is a really bad way of writing code. Although it is a really good way of demonstrating things in a learning scenario.

Comment: See [Char to int implicit cast Behind the Scenes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32094604/char-to-int-implicit-cast-behind-the-scenes) for in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 6):

A string is an array of chars. Here you are casting chars to `int` implicitly which returns the ASCII value of the char:

```
.Select(c => (c * 30))
```

Comment: Thanks. Makes much more sense when you put it like that. :)

Answer (score 0):

[`System.Char` Represents a character as a UTF-16 code unit.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char) … [The value of a Char object is its 16-bit numeric (ordinal) value.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char?view=netframework-4.7.1#remarks)

"A" consists of one UTF-16 code unit, with the value 65.